# Merging Two Dataframes without a Key Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a requirement where I want to merge two data frames without any key column.
[image]

From the input table, I am treating first three columns as one data frame and the last column as another one. My plan is to sort the second data frame and then merge it to the first one without any key column so that it looks like the above output.
Is it possible to merge in this way or if there are any alternatives?

Comment: I think `pd.concat` or `pd.append` is what you're looking for, I'm doing a little digging.

Comment: It looks like you want to sort the comments column?  `df['comments']'= df['comments'].sort_values()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "sort the second dataframe" you mean move the NULL values to the end of the list and keep the rest of the order in tact, then this will get the job done.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'UK', 'Finland', 'Spain', 'Australia'],
                   'Name': ['Sam', 'Chris', 'Jeff', 'Kartik', 'Mavenn']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Comments': ['X', None, 'Y', None, 'Z']})

df1['Comments'] = df2[df2.Comments.notnull()].reset_index().drop(columns='index')

     Country    Name Comments
0        USA     Sam        X
1         UK   Chris        Y
2    Finland    Jeff        Z
3      Spain  Kartik      NaN
4  Australia  Mavenn      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to update the code as per my requirement and accommodate it in the rest of my program. But could you please let me know the use of reset_index and then dropping it off?

Comment: you need to reset the index, so that when you add the Comments to the first dataframe, it does so based on your new ordering. Without it, it will use the original indices giving you the original ordering, which you don’t want. There’s probably a nicer way to stop reset index from creating a column named index, but that drop just removes the unnecessary column

Comment: One doubt, while running the same set of code on the Anaconda version of Python, the drop(columns = 'index' )throws an error stating invalid arguments. @ALollZ

Comment: You must be running an older version of pandas then, as drop was recently updated

Comment: I think you would instead want drop('index', axis=1) if it's before 0.21.0

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `pd.DataFrame.join` after filtering out null values.

Data from @ALollz.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'UK', 'Finland', 'Spain', 'Australia']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Comments': ['X', None, 'Y', None, 'Z']})

res = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(list(filter(None, df2.values)), columns=['comments']))
```

Result:

```
     Country comments
0        USA        X
1         UK        Y
2    Finland        Z
3      Spain      NaN
4  Australia      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
input['Comments'] = input.Comments.sort_values().values
```

Output:

```
  Comments    Country    Name
1        X        USA     Sam
2        Y         UK   Chris
3        Z    Finland    Jeff
4      NaN      Spain  Kartik
5      NaN  Australia   Maven
```